# Is there any way how to click to the Facebook Messenger input field using xpath?

Tags: selenium, intellij-idea, xpath, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

Is there any way how to **click to the Facebook Messenger input field using xpath**?

I tried

```
//*[contains(text(), 'Aa')]
```

but it does not work and there is nothing like input visible in the code.

I used **sikuli** images and it works **when I use Idea** to run the script but **it does not work** when I run it from **Jenkins** server and idk why the path to the images is correct..

[image: Facebook Input Field]

Any ideas on how to click to the input, **please**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works:-

```
.//div[@aria-label='Aa']
```

Comment: Thank you @itronic1990 it works! Can I kindly ask two more questions? 

1. Is there any way of confirming the Show Notification Chrome popup with the Allow / Block options?? I noticed that we can simply get rig of this pop-up by hitting ESC but Idk how to send key without targeting any element on the page - what is the correct way of doing that, please?

2. How can I submit the message? I tried to fill the field with the XPath and it worked but Keys.ENTER did not send the msg..

Thank you once again for the help!